# How to split this csv file into multiple contents?

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have CSV File which having below contents,
**Input.csv**

```
 Sample NiFi Data demonstration for below
Due dates 20-02-2017,23-03-2017

My Input No1 inside csv,,,,,,
Animals,Today-20.02.2017,Yesterday-19-02.2017
Fox,21,32
Lion,20,12
My Input No2 inside csv,,,,
Name,ID,City
Mahi,12,UK
And,21,US

Prabh,32,LI
```

I need to split above whole csv(Input.csv) into two parts like InputNo1.csv and InputNo2.csv.

```
For InputNo1.csv should have below contents only.,

Animals,Today-20.02.2017,Yesterday-19-02.2017
Fox,21,32
Lion,20,12

For InputNo2.csv should have below contents.,

Name,ID,City
Mahi,12,UK
And,21,US

Prabh,32,LI
```

Is this possible to convert csv into Multiple parts in NiFi possible with existing processors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Use the `ReplaceText` processor to remove the global header, use `SplitContent` to split the resulting flowfile into multiple flowfiles, use another `ReplaceText` to remove the leftover comment string because `SplitContent` needs a literal byte string, not a regex, and then perform the normal `SplitText` operations.

Here is a [template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/4414529f84f64ea6f270d630be1c6ada) specific to the input you provided in your question.

[image: Split multiple CSV template]